# Using MediaCodec to trim causes black frames when advancing encoder to reach newStartAt time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediacodec

I'm using MediaCodec to trim a video providing a startAt and endAt time where the trim happens.
when I use:
`extractor.seekTo(startMs * 1000.toLong(), MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC)` I don't get any black frames but there is a slight margin between startAt and the actual startAt When the trim is done, let's say I set startAt to be `5_000`, the result I get is `4_500`.

Now to rectify that I tried using:

```
val seekToTime = startMs * 1_000
extractor.seekTo(seekToTime, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC)
// Discard samples until reaching the exact start time
while (extractor.sampleTime < seekToTime) {
   extractor.advance()
}
```

using this I get an extremely close trim but there are black frames at the beginning.

Here is the full code below:

```
suspend fun editVideo(videoFilePath: String, mediaEdit: KPMediaEdit) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val startMs: Long = ((mediaEdit.trims.firstOrNull()?.startAt ?: 0.0) * 1_000).toLong()
        val endMs: Long = ((mediaEdit.trims.firstOrNull()?.endAt ?: 0.0) * 1_000).toLong()

        val useAudio = mediaEdit.hasSound
        val useVideo = true

        pDebug("UseAudio = $useAudio - startMs = $startMs - endMs = $endMs", "EditVideo")

        // Input and Output files setup remains the same
        val inputFile = File(videoFilePath)
        val outputFilePath = inputFile.absolutePath.replace(".mp4", "_edited.mp4")
        val outputFile = File(outputFilePath)

        val extractor = MediaExtractor()
        extractor.setDataSource(videoFilePath)
        val trackCount = extractor.trackCount
        val muxer = MediaMuxer(outputFilePath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)

        // Set up the tracks and retrieve the max buffer size for selected
        // tracks.
        val indexMap = HashMap<Int, Int>(trackCount)
        var bufferSize = -1
        for (i in 0 until trackCount) {
            val format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i)
            val mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME)
            var selectCurrentTrack = false
            if (mime?.startsWith("audio/") == true && useAudio) {
                selectCurrentTrack = true
            } else if (mime?.startsWith("video/") == true && useVideo) {
                selectCurrentTrack = true
            }
            if (selectCurrentTrack) {
                extractor.selectTrack(i)
                val dstIndex = muxer.addTrack(format)
                indexMap[i] = dstIndex
                if (format.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE)) {
                    val newSize = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE)
                    bufferSize = if (newSize > bufferSize) newSize else bufferSize
                }
            }
        }
        if (bufferSize < 0) {
            bufferSize = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
        }
        // Set up the orientation and starting time for the extractor.
        val retrieverSrc = MediaMetadataRetriever()

        try {
            retrieverSrc.setDataSource(videoFilePath)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            pDebug(e.toString(), "EditVideo")
        }
        val degreesString =
            retrieverSrc.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION)
        if (!degreesString.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val degrees = Integer.parseInt(degreesString)
            if (degrees >= 0) {
                muxer.setOrientationHint(degrees)
            }
        }

        if (startMs > 0) {
            val seekToTime = startMs * 1_000
            extractor.seekTo(seekToTime, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC)
            // Discard samples until reaching the exact start time
            while (extractor.sampleTime < seekToTime) {
                extractor.advance()
            }
            pDebug("Track: SeekTo: ${startMs * 1000}, ${extractor.sampleTime}", "EditVideo")
        }
        //val newStartAt = extractor.sampleTime
        // Copy the samples from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer. We will loop
        // for copying each sample and stop when we get to the end of the source
        // file or exceed the end time of the trimming.
        val offset = 0
        var trackIndex = -1
        val dstBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize)
        val bufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()

        // Calculate the total duration and trimming duration for progress reporting
        val totalDuration = endMs - startMs
        val trimmingDuration = totalDuration.toDouble()

        try {
            muxer.start()

            while (true) {
                bufferInfo.offset = offset
                bufferInfo.size = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset)
                if (bufferInfo.size < 0) {
                    pDebug("Trim - Saw input EOS", "EditVideo")
                    bufferInfo.size = 0
                    break
                }
                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractor.sampleTime
                if (endMs > 0 && bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs > endMs * 1000.toLong()) {
                    pDebug("Trim - The current sample is over the trim end time", "EditVideo")
                    break
                }
                bufferInfo.flags = extractor.sampleFlags
                trackIndex = extractor.sampleTrackIndex
                muxer.writeSampleData(indexMap[trackIndex]!!, dstBuf, bufferInfo)
                extractor.advance()

                // Calculate progress and invoke callback if needed
                val currentProgress = ((bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs / 1000).toInt() - startMs).toDouble()
                val progressPercentage = (currentProgress / trimmingDuration * 100).toInt()
                //progressCallback.invoke(progressPercentage)
            }
            muxer.stop()

            // Call the progress callback with 100 to indicate completion
            //progressCallback.invoke(100)
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            // Swallow the exception due to malformed source.
            pDebug("Trim - The source video file is malformed", "EditVideo")
            //errorCallback(e)
        } finally {
            extractor.release()
            retrieverSrc.release()
            muxer.release()
        }

        outputFile.renameTo(inputFile)
    }
```

`DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1 * 1024 * 1024`

How do I get as close as possible to my desired startAt time? is it possible to fix the black frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, you are copying **encoded** video frames from an input file to an output file.

Note that a video stream consists of different [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types) of frames. I-frames contain complete images, while P-frames and B-frames are partial.

If you seek the `MediaExtractor` to the nearest I-frame using `SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC` and then skip it because the frame time is too early, you are actually throwing away the information required for decoding the following partial frames.

You basically have a couple of options:

1. Live with the fact that the result it not 100% accurate (compensated by the fact that the process is fast)
2. Decode the video frames starting from the closest I-frame using one `MediaCodec`, ignore those **decoded** frames that are not within the desired time range, and encode the rest of the frames back using another `MediaCodec` (this workflow will be slow but accurate)